# Changes to the contents of a control variable linked to a static text box doesn't reflect in the dialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a `CString` variable which is linked to a static text box inside one of my dialogs, lets call it controlVariable. When I click the START button inside this dialog a couple of things happen. First I update the contents of the controlVariable (to say something like "initialization begun"). I do `UpdateData(FALSE)` and then run an initialization of another class (which starts some threads). This initialization takes some time, so this is why the contents of the static text box need to reflect that while its running. But the changes aren't reflected until the `OnBnClickedStart()` function finishes. I'm having trouble having the changes to this controlVariable reflect in the dialog.

What I've tried:

- `UpdateData(FALSE)` after changing the controlVariable using basic CString append functions (e.g. CString A = str1 + str2;) and changing the control variable using .format() (e.g. controlVariable.format(_T("some text")); )
- Running `OnPaint()` after changing the controlVariable contents
- I went into debug mode and the program runs into the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP section of the dialog class and just loops there until I step out of it. The contents of the static text box linked to my controlVariable aren't updated until I step out of BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP. So the contents of my static text box don't even update at the end of my OnBnClickedStart() funciton.

Example Code:

```
CMyClass someClass;

CString controlVariable; // linked to some static text in the SomeDlgClass

void SomeDlgClass::OnBnClickedStart() 
{
    controlVariable = CString("System initialized\r\n"); // Also tried 
    UpdateData(FALSE); // Also tried OnPaint()

    someClass.initialize(); // I would like the static text box to update before I run this
}
```

So when I'm running this, my main dialog seems like it's "frozen" - I can't move the window around or click any of the buttons. Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you put `PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, button_id)` as the last thing in `OnInitDialog`. `button_id` is for `OnBnClickedStart`. You could post a minimum version of your dialog, use `Sleep` to simulate long wait.

Comment: If you are running a lengthy operation then the system might be choking.  Either move the lengthy operation into a worker thread or possible use UpdateWindow to force a repaint.

Comment: Don't attempt to write MFC code until you understand Windows API programming. Message handling is strictly synchronous. While you are in a message handler, no other messages are dispatched. That's why you don't see the changes reflected until after leaving the handler. Blocking a GUI thread is never a good idea. You need to offload time-consuming operations, establishing proper synchronization. Not an easy task.